# Chaining events and DOM iteration

Tags: jquery

Below I've got two jQuery selectors.

The first searches for a DOM element within a cached object and then searches its parents, then it seaches the parents (table) for another dom element. **(ex. 2)**

The second (2 lines) searches via the cached element.
**(ex. 1)**

```
    $('element', table.setting.body).on('blur focus', table.focus).parents('parent').find('another element').on('click', function); // ex2

    $('element', table.setting.body).on('blur focus', function); // ex 1
    $('another element', table.setting.body).on('click', function); // ex 1
```

Which one is faster/best practice?
Ex. 1 would without doubt be faster reffering to jQuery functions, ie. `.hide().animate().show()` but, when is it when searching for DOM elements?

[image]

Comment: The difference between the two is going to be very small, probably not worth worrying over. I would go with option 2 simply becuase it's going to be easier to maintain.

Comment: In this particular example i agree, but working on a larger scale application og binding multiple elements / iterating a larger dom, it maybe would make a difference, i don't know. It's just nice to know, it could be usefull in other examples.

Comment: I suppose it would also depend on the structure of your page. If you can *guarantee* that both `element` and `another element` are both children of `parent` then either should work fine. Option 2 would be better if there's ever a chance `another element` could be located elsewhere on the page. I personally prefer Option 2.

Comment: Somehow you messed up between Ex1 in the code and Ex1 in text and example image. Nevertheless, I set up a few jsperfs and indeed the one using the cached element (without .parent()) was always slightly faster

Comment: I edited the document to correct the mistake, is your jsperfs taking the cached element into account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to match different descendants from `table.setting.body` and perform different tasks on these descendants, without having to specify `table.setting.body` twice.

You can use [end()](http://api.jquery.com/end/) to achieve this. For instance, if `table.setting.body` is a jQuery object, you can write:

```
table.setting.body.find("element").on("blur focus", function).end()
                  .find("another element").on("click", function);
```

(If `table.setting.body` is a DOM element, you will have to apply `$()` to it first).

The code above only evaluates the cached object once, performs two calls to `find()` (slightly faster than your calls to `$()` with a `context` argument in my experience), two calls to `on()` (the same as yours) and a single call to `end()` (which only pops an item off a stack and should be quite fast).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this is less a question of speed but more a question of maintainability and good coding style.

And that is where Example 1 is far better than Example 2.

Avoid confusion and keep things separated. You want to attach 2 events to 2 different element - write 2 statements. This makes your code far more structured and readable.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I see is the usage of parents inside your first approach. jQuery.parents looks for the needed parent using a loop inside the function dir:

```
parents: function( elem ) {
    return jQuery.dir( elem, "parentNode" );
},

// ...

dir: function( elem, dir, until ) {
    var matched = [],
        cur = elem[ dir ];

    while ( cur && cur.nodeType !== 9 && (until === undefined || cur.nodeType !== 1 || !jQuery( cur ).is( until )) ) {
        if ( cur.nodeType === 1 ) {
            matched.push( cur );
        }
        cur = cur[dir];
    }
    return matched;
},
```

(http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js)

`cur = elem[ dir ]` means `elem["parentNode"]` and is repeated for all parents, because until is undefined. There is no shortcut if the wanted parent is given as reference.

Depending on the path length between the first element you are looking for and the document's root the first approach needs more DOM operations.

Therefore I recommend the second approach.